# Dynamic 1D and 2D array c++ crash

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I have already dynamically allocated the 1D array, int *x, and the 2D array, int **y. I am trying to display the sum of the dynamic 1D and 2D arrays determined by the lengths the user inputs. I have to run the program twice for the length 5 and 10 for the 1D array, and lengths 3,5 and 6,7 for the 2D array.  It is crashing and not displaying any sums on the console. Please help!

`#include <iostream>`

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    float sum2 =0.0;
    float sum3 = 0.0; //1d array length 10
    //1d array dynamic allocation
    //2d array dynamic allocation
    int length; //user length for 2d array, 5
    int length2 = 3; //length for 2d array, 3
    float oneArray; //length for 1d array
    float oneArray2; // 1D array
    int length1;
    float sum4=0.0;

    cout << "Enter dimensions " << endl;
    cin >> length >> oneArray2;

    cout << "Enter dimensions for 2d array " << endl;
    cin >> length2 >> oneArray;


    int *x = new int[oneArray2]; //single

    int **y = new int* [length2]; //creates array


    for(int i= 0; i < length; i++) //initializing 2d array
        for(int j =0; j < length2; j++)
        {
            y[i][j] = i*j;
        }


    //initialize for 1d array
    for(int l=0; l < oneArray2; l++)
    {
        x[l] = l;
    }


    for(int i= 0; i < length; i++) // allocating for 2d array
        {
            y[i] = new int[5];

        }

    for(int i=0; i< oneArray2; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + x[i];
        cout << sum;

    }

    for(int k=0; k < length1; k++){

        sum3 = sum3 + x[k];
        cout << sum3;
    }



    for(int i= 0; i < length; i++) //initializing
        for(int j =0; j < length2; j++)
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + y[i][j];
            cout << sum2;

        }

    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < 7; j++)
        {

            sum4 = sum4 + y[i][j];
            cout << sum4;
        }


    for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < length2; j++)
        {
        delete[] y[i][j]; //error message here too

        }


    for (int i=0; i < oneArray2; i++)
         delete[] y[i];


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are initializing the 2d array before allocating all its memory.

Comment: [An alternative.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) This makes a 2D array out of a 1D array. Much easier to wrangle and often much faster due to improved spatial locality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you allocate memory for the 2d array before you initialize it not the other way around

Second

the correct way to deallocate that memory for a 2D array is

```
for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
 //first you deallocate every row y[i]
 delete [] y[i];

delete [] y;
```

and for the 1D array

```
delete[] x;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For the deallocation for the 2d array, I'm still getting an error message, on this line       delete y[i][j];     that says you can't delete expression of type 'int'

Comment: check the edited you can't deallocate y[i][j] its like saying int a; then try to deallocate but you didn't even allocate it..on the other hand y[i] is allocated & y is allocated so you gotta deallocate them

Comment: I see, I allocated y[i] here: y[i] = new int[5]; and allocated y here: int **y = new int* [length2]; ?? Is that correct?

Comment: That makes sense. I did the correct deallocation for both. Thank you very much!!  I'm kinda confused how to check to see if the results are right. Do you know how I could check to see if they are correct (for the 2D array 3,5?)

Comment: yes i think it s all good just here for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) you should actually go to the number of rows & columns in your 2D array not to 6 & 7 because with the example 3,5 you'll be having out of bound exception